# Fire And Forget vs Publish Subscribe

Tags: apache-kafka, message-queue, publish-subscribe, fire-and-forget

I know that Fire And Forget is a pattern that lets you add a message in the Messaging Queue and don't wait for an acknowledgment.
Also, I know that Pub/Sub is a pattern that publishers will publish and subscribers will consume the data.
What is the difference between these two patterns in the Message Queues(Kafka)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Kafka, it's exactly as you've described; there's no "vs" as it's different sides of the protocol and they aren't exclusive

Disable producer acks, it's fire and forget. Producers always push.

Consumers always subscribe.